# Django Social-auth returning URLError

Tags: django, facebook, twitter, django-socialauth

Am using django social-auth authentication for my app.After login to facebook or twitter from my app it is returning error

`URLError at /complete/facebook/`

`Exception Value: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden>`

`Exception Location:   /usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py in do_open, line 1145`

Backends,url's,Appid and secret id added.it is connefcting correctly but returning back with error

Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show us your code and possible trackbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your issue was fixed https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/148/?